# Apache home server connects to domain inside network and not out

Tags: apache, xampp

Hello i have an old windows xp pc im trying to turn into a server for hobbyist purposes. I downloaded and installed the apache xampp 1.8 distribution. Once installed and tested that the localhost worked, I connected my domain to my servers ip. So my problem is when i tried to connect to my site on my pc on the same network, they all were able to load the domain/site inside the network successfully but when i have a pc thats outside the network try it fails. Any ideas?. thanks.

Comment: Did you use a pubic IP? Did you set the firewall on the router to let incoming connections to port 80? Did you set the apache to respond to virtual host?

Comment: i think i used the ip that uniquely identifies the computer on the network. i have my firewall off but i also set the exceptions for port 80 for tcp and udp. Also i dont think i set apache to respond to the virtual host since i havent touched the vhost.config file.

Comment: On which network, local or public? If it is 192.168.x.y or 10.x.y.z it will not work.

Comment: i think its public i used a 192...etc, does that mean i cant use my private home network to host it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used a private IP instead of public IP so it does not get resolved to your server. You have to use a public IP (if you have a static IP from your provider you have to setup port forwarding on your router.) If you get the IP from DHCPD server you will need to use dynamic DNS and port forwarding.

More info on private networks: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network

Comment: Thanks i easily found my public ip and reset the proper information. It now runs outside my network!! Many Thanks.